# How to restore windows server raid 1 setup?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, raid, server-setup

I have a machine that was running software windows raid 1. Somehow, after restart raid configuration failed and now two drives are separate volumes. I can't find an option to restore raid configuration or create new raid 1 setup without erasing both drives.

How do I restore previous software raid 1 configuration?

Edit:
Drives were in mirror setup for storage, not boot. Both drives are now dynamic, simple volumes.

Comment: Confirm data is good on one drive, delete the partition on the mirror drive and rebuild it.

Comment: Data was good on both drives. But I tried what you suggested and it worked. I was afraid to delete a working volume. Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm data is good on one drive, delete the partition on the mirror drive and rebuild it.